# Python - request data from a dataset using a varible as the column name

Tags: python-3.x

how can i request data from a dataset using a varible as the column name?
for example, I try to get the data in "data_set" where I insert the column name using "var_name":

```
a =  data_set.'{}'[1].format(var_name)
```

Comment: Try instead: `a =  data_set[var_name[1]]`.

Comment: Or else: `a =  getattr(data_set,'{}'[1].format(var_name)`

Answer (score 0):

for "a" being you dataset, you can try:

var_name = 'ColumnName'

print(a[var_name])